# A F5 or Refresh calling in the page is a postback?

Tags: richfaces

I would want to know actually what is a F5 event for RichFaces ?

I have found other interesting article:

[How to know if I am in a postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427272/how-to-know-if-i-am-in-a-postback)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a F5 event"?

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

Normally, fetching a page is a GET request, and F5 just does another GET.
You can not detect 'F5', but instead should detect if the request is 'GET' or 'POST'.

If you fill out a form, and click "submit", and then do an F5 after that, you will typically get a warning from your browser because it will do another POST.

For instance, Firefox will say: "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier. [Resend] [Cancel]"

Thus, an F5 might be either a GET or POST, and you need to be able to deal with either.

One way to keep your users from getting this message from their browser is to use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) idiom.

It can be confusing when using some web frameworks, because things that don't look like form submit buttons (causing a POST) actually are. For instance, in ASP.NET, clicking a link might do a postback, where normally that is not the case.