# JSF 2.3.14: Syntax error after (re-) rendering a JavaScript code block with constants

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, mojarra, jsf-2.3

The following code fragment generates a javascript syntax error when I push the `h:commandButton`:

```html
<h:outputScript>
  'use strict';
  const label = '*';
</h:outputScript>
<h:form>
  <h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax render="@all" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

`SyntaxError: redeclaration of const label`

The problem is the `const label = '*'`. How to deal with that in this case?

Mojarra 2.3.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `h:outputScript` conditional, based on `facesContext.postback`. If you use `rendered="#{not facesContext.postback}"` it will only be rendered in the initial request and not with Ajax requests:

```html
<h:outputScript rendered="#{not facesContext.postback}">
  'use strict';
  const label = '*';
</h:outputScript>
<h:form>
  <h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax render="@all" />
  </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

See also:

- [How to know if I am in a postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427272/how-to-know-if-i-am-in-a-postback)